# Google play can't find my app

Tags: android, google-play

I just published my App in the Play Store.
I noticed that I cannot find my App if I search with the name of the app, but I can find it only with similar keyword but not with the name!

This seem strange to me, anyone know why? Someone know how the search work?

p.s. There are only 2 other app with the same name....

Maybe they looking for the package name? Not the name of the App?....

Comment: It takes some time to publish the app in GStore..  maybe is not published yet. :/

Comment: what is the name of your app? what keywords are you using? you could file a ticket to google play support.

Comment: Let's say my app name is "Get time in Twitter", I can't find it with "Get time in Twitter" ! But with "Get time" I can found it in the 4° position....

Comment: I'll try to wait some days... than I'll open a ticket